# gitlab CD/CI how to deploy artifacts to the server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My pipeline is successfully building the artefacts but I have no idea (and to be honest as the more I read the more I am confused) how to deploy to the directory on my server

I completely do not understand what to do to simply copy artifacts to the directory on my server.

```
image: gul-doxygen:latest

stages:
  - pages
  - deploy

pages:
  stage: pages
  script:
    - echo "executing the doxygen"
    - doxygen ./Doxyfile
    - apt update
    - apt install tree
    - tree -d
    - mv --verbose documentation/html/ public/  
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - DOXYGEN-MASTER 

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - pages
  script:
    - echo "Hello world"
```

What should I put in the script part?

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you are storing your build in the `public` directory using artifacts. To deploy, you simply need to copy these binaries from this directory to the directory of your server.

To do this, microsoft has a built in `robocopy` command. Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy.

Here is an example cmd script:

```
SET server=<ip_address_here>

robocopy <source> <destination> [<file>[ ...]] [<options>]

PAUSE
```

Comment: this directory does not exists. (it is not visible on the server).

Comment: @0___________ Ideally, you want your gitlab runner and other resources to be on a VM on the server, that way it can easily access any necessary files. Consider restructuring as such.

Comment: @0___________ See https://medium.com/@gabriel.faraday.barros/gitlab-ci-cd-with-net-framework-39220808b18f. there is a useful sample code on deploying at the end.

Comment: It is not what I am lloking for